# Inner Join Two Column From Another Table with Custom Column Name

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table called tbl_project_requirements and tbl_units. I want select all from tbl_project_requirements and want join id as unit_id and name as unit_name from tbl_units. My current query is like below

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_requirements` INNER JOIN tbl_units AS t2 WHERE unit_type = t2.id
```

Its working fine but giving me id as id and name as name so there multiple column with same column name in my result like below

[image]

Let me know if someone can help me for solve the puzzle. 
Thanks

Comment: Your current query does not appear to have any join condition, and I doubt this is what you really intend to be running.  Please add sample data to your question and describe further what you goal is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use alias for 2nd table's id and Name column

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.id as t2id, t2.name as t2Name
FROM `tbl_requirements` t1 INNER JOIN tbl_units AS t2 
on unit_type = t2.id
```